# Multiple .cpp programs in xcode project?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4

I'm using Xcode to do the Project Euler problems in C++. I wanted to keep everything organized, so I decided to make a single project that would include all my .cpp files, like in visual studio. The problem that I am encountering is I have one project called "Project Euler" and then I wanted to have Problem1.ccp, Problem2.cpp, etc. enabling the ones I want to run. When I did that, I got an error "Apple Mach-O Linker Error". Does anyone know how I could do what I'm trying to do with Xcode?

Comment: Read the doc and learn how to manage multiple targets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is one Xcode target per problem (assuming that each problem has a `main()`).

To add a target to the current project (Xc4), go to `File > New > New Target…`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you want to add a new Target using justin's steps.

You also need to understand what a target is: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html

and how to run and compile the separate files:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeBuild.html

To paraphrase, a target is a completely separate product contained in the same Xcode project.

When you want to change which target you're running/compiling/analyzing you need to adjust the scheme. In Xcode version 4.6.2 go to:

```
Product > Scheme > Desired Target
```